# (browserify) Error : Cannot find module 'web3/lib/solidity/coder.js'

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-invocation, javascript

When I use command `browserify viz.js -o main.js` to build [this project](https://github.com/tomconte/solarchain-dashboard), I receive following error message :

```
C:\Users\KX5710\Downloads\GUI_solarchain\solarchain-dashboard-master>browserify
viz.js -o main.js
Error: Cannot find module 'web3/lib/solidity/coder.js' from 'C:\Users\KX5710\Dow
nloads\GUI_solarchain\solarchain-dashboard-master'
    at C:\Users\KX5710\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\
browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:46:17
    at process (C:\Users\KX5710\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node
_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (C:\Users\KX5710\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_m
odules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:188:17)
    at load (C:\Users\KX5710\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_mo
dules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:69:43)
    at onex (C:\Users\KX5710\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_mo
dules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:92:31)
    at C:\Users\KX5710\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\
browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
```

**Do i need to install some additional package ? or the problem is something else ?**